# How to detect line feed in between two Strings or int using scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Question:

I have this set of number in a .txt document, I want to use `java.util.Scanner` to detect the line feed in between `123`, `456`, and `789`, print out the numbers in between the line feeds, is there any way to do so?

```
1 2 3
// \n here
4 5 6
// \n here
7 8 9
```

Output:
`456`

===========================================================================

Solutions that I tried:

(1) I tried using hasNextLine() method, however, it seems like hasNextLine() will tell me are there tokens in the next line and return a boolean instead of telling me is there \n. `if (scan.hasNextLine()) { \\ do something }`

(2) I also tried using: (However, using such condition will say *"Syntax error on token 'Invalid Character'"*)

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

// create int[] nums

while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String temp = scan.next();
    if (temp == \n) {
        // nums.add(); something like this
    }
}

System.out.print(nums); // something like this
```

I am thinking using `\n` as delimiters

ps. I did google and most of the results tell me to use .hasNextLine(), but I want it to identify a line feed (\n)

Comment: The scanner might be automatically consuming white-space.

Comment: Just read a line at a time with nextLine?

Comment: You say you want to identify a **linefeed**.  Think of it instead as an **empty line**,  or a line of **length zero**.  Go ahead and give `nextLine()` a try.  Or, chuck the `Scanner` and use a `BufferedReader` instead.

Comment: @KevinAnderson My teacher wishes to not use `java.io.BufferedReader` because he only taught `java.util.Scanner`

Comment: @EvanKnowles Scanner will actually skip the \n and print the line with tokens instead.

Comment: By `line feed` you mean: `1 2 3\n \n 4 5 6` or `1 2 3\n4 5 6`?

Comment: `1 2 3 \n 4 5 6`, having `java.util.Scanner` detect the `\n` in between `123` and `456`

Comment: And by `detect` means to print the line number where is present `\n` or the `indexOf` from `1 2 3 \n 4 5 6`?

Comment: where `\n` present but not printing, getting the numbers after `\n`

Comment: @FlashSonic526 what is the output that you expect? Do you want the output of your program to print `\n` in the console like `1 2 3\n\n4 5 6`?
By reading "to detect the line feed in between" seemed like you trying to find all the indexes of `\n` !?

Comment: Correct, I want to find all indexes of `\n`

Comment: @FlashSonic526 In that case I already answered your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` scans the next element by using `new-line` or `whitespace` as a delimiter by default. To let it read the whole content use `scan.useDelimiter("\\Z")`.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");
final String content = scan.next();   // content: "1 2 3\r\n\r\n4 5 6"
int index = 0;
System.out.println("Index of \\n");
while (index != -1) {
     index = content.indexOf("\n", index);
     if (index != -1) {
          System.out.println(index);
          // Or do whatever you wish
          index++;
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Index of \n
5
7
```

Comment: `indexOf()` returns `-1` when it can't find `"\n"`. `0` indicates the starting index of the match.

Comment: I see, I wonder why the result has 7 while 6 is the biggest number in the content?

Comment: @FlashSonic526, in his example there are 2 `\n`: `"1 2 3\r\n\r\n4 5 6"` - 5 and 7 represents the index of `\n` in that String.

Comment: I wonder did you make `\n` a string? Isn't index counts from 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String data = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Data: " + data);

    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Found it");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The string data will read every line one by one and store the whole line in a String and then checks if that string is emty.

Comment: it worked, but isn't the `scanner` will skip `\n` by default?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, when answering a question don't post just code. Add also an explanation of what your code does and why you think your answer is a good fit for the question.

Comment: @MarioCodes This piece of code will just read every line in the file and store that line in a String then it will check if that line is empty by using the .isEmpty().

Comment: Don't just answer me as a comment, add it to your answer for the sake of completion

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand 100% your question. So I'm assuming your file always will have 2 lines separated by **ONLY ONE** new line(`\n`). If I'm wrong please tell it.

```
String charsAfterNewLine = null;

//try-catch block with resources
//Scanner need to be closed (scan.close()) after finish with it
//this kind of block will do `scan.close()` automatically
try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))){

    //consume(skip) first line
    if(scan.hasNextLine()){
        scan.nextLine();
    }else{
        throw new Exception("File is empty");
    }

    //get second line
    if(scan.hasNextLine()){
        charsAfterNewLine = scan.nextLine();
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Missing second line");
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("charsAfterNewLine: " + charsAfterNewLine);
```

If you want simple way, without try-catch:

```
String charsAfterNewLine = null;

//throws FileNotFoundException
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

if(scan.hasNextLine()){

    //consume(skip) first line
    scan.nextLine();

    if(scan.hasNextLine()){

        //get second line
        charsAfterNewLine = scan.nextLine();

    }else{
        System.out.println("Missing second line");
    }

}else{
    System.out.println("File is empty");
}

scan.close();

System.out.println("charsAfterNewLine: " + charsAfterNewLine);
```

Results(for both):

```
Input: 
    (empty file)
Output: 
    File is empty
    charsAfterNewLine: null

-----

Input:
    1 2 3 4 5 6
Output:
    Missing second line
    charsAfterNewLine: null

-----

Input:
    1 2 3\n4 5 6
Output:
    charsAfterNewLine: 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your recommendation worked in my original question. However, as I move forward, I have to revise my question a bit. Please kindly advise further with thanks.

Comment: @FlashSonic526, can u also show the output for that input? It will be more easy to understand your question.

Comment: I just updated the question for clarity, see whether does it help? Thanks!

Comment: @FlashSonic526, the code should works. Even with `1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9` it still prints `4 5 6`. The code need minimum 2 lines. If he has more than 2 lines doesn't matter. He reads just first 2 lines and the rest are ignored.